# When we pass ref prop in the parent component and get the prop in child component what is the type of ref in typescript in child component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

In start i have define the useRef Hook and then i have passed ref variable to ref prop in the child component form the parent component.

```
const weightRef = useRef<TextInput>(null);

<ChildComponent
name={"weight"}
ref={weightRef}
/>
```

```
export interface TextInputProps {
  name:"string";
  ref?: any;  //Here what is the type of ref for now i have used any
}
```

I need correct type of ref instead of any

Comment: In any decent IDE, and in the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play), you can get the answer to this kind of question by hovering your mouse over `weightRef` in your first line of code above. It would show `MutableRefObject<TextInput>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `fowardref` to pass ref to child component

```
export interface TextInputProps {
  name:"string"; 
}


const FancyButton = React.forwardRef<TextInput , TextInputProps>((props, ref) => (
```

refer [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) for available element types

Comment: Now the child component gives me this error: 
Type 'Ref<TextInput> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'MutableRefObject<TextInput> | null | undefined'.

Comment: ah if you want to use the ref in the child component, use forward ref

Comment: yes i am using forward ref but if i don't define the type of ref prop it also gives me error

Comment: sample demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-hl21sp?file=App.tsx

Comment: Types of parameters 'inputRef' and 'ref' are incompatible.
    Type 'ForwardedRef<TextInput>' is not assignable to type 'MutableRefObject<TextInput | null>'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'MutableRefObject<TextInput | null>'.

Comment: see the update op

Comment: export const FormikInput: React.FC<FormikInputProps> = React.forwardRef(
  (
    { name, ...otherProps },
    inputRef: React.MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement | null>
  ) =>{

TS gives me this error:
 Type 'ForwardedRef<HTMLInputElement>' is not assignable to type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement | null>'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement | null>'.

Comment: My problem is solved i was giving React.FC type to forwardRef component Thanks